# Simple timer App where it counts the number of seconds that have gone by since it's start shows an incorrect time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-timer

I am new to flutter and decided to build a simple timer app, that counts the number of seconds that have gone by since it's start and it ends up showing the wrong time. The timer starts off with 0, then increments to 1 and, from there on out it seems as if it is increasing exponentially.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'app.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());
```

**app.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'clock_widget.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
 @override

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  title: "Timer",
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Timer"),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ClockWidget(),
            Text("seconds", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 35),)
          ],
        )
      ],
    )
  ),
);
}
```

**clock_widget.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ClockWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ClockWidgetState createState() => ClockWidgetState();
}

class ClockWidgetState extends State<ClockWidget> {
  @override
  int _secondCount = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => (setState(() {_secondCount+=1;})));
    print("${_secondCount}");
    return Text("${_secondCount}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 75, color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 144, 255, 1)),);
  }
}
```

I have tried numberous methods but to me this seemed like the simplest one and logically it seems correct. After every second setState is called which increments _secondsCount.

[The app's second count hardly 15 seconds after running it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbAEF.png)

Comment: Have you tried `_secondCount=t.tick` intsead of incrementing?

Comment: Every second, at every build method invocation, you create a new Timer. All of these timers are adding a second to _secondCount. Define your Timer only once, in initState. Example in the answer below

Comment: @the0val No I haven't but I'll definitely try it out Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently defining new `Timer`s every second. Each of these timers is incrementing the number of seconds.

You want to define your `Timer` only once and outside of the `build` method.

1. Create a Timer in `initState`
2. Update state every second
3. Display the seconds in the `build` method
4. Cancel the `Timer` in `dispose`

Here's an example:

```
class ClockWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ClockWidgetState createState() => ClockWidgetState();
}

class ClockWidgetState extends State<ClockWidget> {
  Timer _timer;
  int _secondCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        this._secondCount += 1;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("${_secondCount}");
    return Text(
      "${_secondCount}",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 75, color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 144, 255, 1)),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't take into account the fact that I was creating the timer each second, the exponential increase in the seconds count was a clear indicator. I'll say this again thank you.